# "Notion" and "conception"

Tags: meaning, nouns

What is the difference between *notion* and *conception*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to The Free Online Dictionary, here is a comparison of synonyms of *idea*:

> Synonyms: idea, thought, notion, concept, conception
>
> These nouns refer to what is formed or represented in the mind as the product of mental activity.
>
> **Idea** has the widest range: "Human history is in essence a history of ideas" (H.G. Wells).
>
> **Thought** is distinctively intellectual and stresses contemplation and reasoning: *"Language is the dress of thought"* (Samuel Johnson).
>
> **Notion** often refers to a vague, general, or even fanciful idea: *"She certainly has some notion of drawing"* (Rudyard Kipling).
>
> **Concept** and **conception** are applied to mental formulations on a broad scale: You seem to have absolutely no concept of time. *"Every succeeding scientific discovery makes greater nonsense of old-time conceptions of sovereignty"* (Anthony Eden).

Comment: still confused. what's the diff between idea and mental formulation.

Answer (score 2):

One can have many notions about a single concept but a notion usually cannot be about many concepts.

Answer (score 1):

According to dictionary.com, a [notion](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/notion?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic) is a vague or imperfect conception.

Thus we may talk about a person having "odd notions" concerning something. On the other hand we may a person has a very "clear conception" of a topic.

So there is a good deal of overlap in meaning but if you wish to emphasise the imperfect nature of an idea you may use notion.